# in magento2 how catalog_product_entity_media_gallery related to catalog_product_entity?

Tags: magento2, gallery

I am debugging magmi-m2 plugin for image importing and noticed SQL query like this :

```
    SELECT catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value_id
    FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
    JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar ON catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.entity_id=catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id
    AND catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value=catalog_product_entity_varchar.value
    AND catalog_product_entity_varchar.attribute_id=?
    WHERE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.entity_id=?
      AND catalog_product_entity_varchar.store_id=?
```

But there is no table column `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.entity_id`, how does table `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` related to specific product ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another table **"catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity"**

That joint "catalog_product_entity_media_gallery" and "catalog_product_entity" table.

Answer (score 0):

About Magento2.3.x

SELECT e.sku,at_path.*
    -> FROM catalog_product_entity e
    -> LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity AS v ON e.row_id = v.row_id
    -> LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS at_path ON (at_path.value_id=v.value_id)
    -> WHERE e.`sku`='SAMPLE0001'\G;